# SBT cannot append Seq[Object] to Seq[ModuleID]

Tags: scala, sbt

SBT keeps failing with improper append errors. Im using the exact format of build files I have seen numerous times.

build.sbt:

```
lazy val backend = (project in file("backend")).settings(
name := "backend",
libraryDependencies ++= (Dependencies.backend)
).dependsOn(api).aggregate(api)
```

dependencies.scala:

```
import sbt._

object Dependencies {

lazy val backend = common ++ metrics

val common = Seq(
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % Version.akka,
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % Version.akka,
"org.scalanlp.breeze" %% "breeze" % Version.breeze,
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-contrib" % Version.akka,
"org.scalanlp.breeze-natives" % Version.breeze,
"com.google.guava" % "guava" % "17.0"
)

val metrics = Seq("org.fusesource" % "sigar" % "1.6.4")
```

Im Im not quite why SBT is complaining

```
error: No implicit for Append.Values[Seq[sbt.ModuleID], Seq[Object]] found,
so Seq[Object] cannot be appended to Seq[sbt.ModuleID]
libraryDependencies ++= (Dependencies.backend)
                    ^
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Short Version (TL;DR)

There's an error in `common`: you want to replace this line

```
"org.scalanlp.breeze-natives" % Version.breeze,
```

with this line

```
"org.scalanlp" %% "breeze-natives" % Version.beeze,
```

---

## Long Version

1. `"org.scalanlp.breeze-natives" % Version.breeze` is a `GroupArtifactID` not a `ModuleID`.
2. This causes `common` to become a `Seq[Object]` instead of a `Seq[ModuleID]`.
3. And therefore also `Dependencies.backend` to be a `Seq[Object]`
4. Which ultimately can't be appended (via `++=`) to `libraryDependencies` (defined as a `SettingKey[Seq[ModuleID]]`) because there is no available `Append.Values[Seq[sbt.ModuleID], Seq[Object]]`.

Answer (score 1):

One of `common` or `metrics` is not a `Seq[sbt.ModuleID]`. You could find out which with a type ascription:

```
val common: Seq[sbt.ModuleID] = ...
val metrics: Seq[sbt.ModuleID] = ...
```

My money is on `common`, this line doesn't have enough `%`s in it:

```
"org.scalanlp.breeze-natives" % Version.breeze
```