# Play Framework SBT import play.api.libs.streams

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am building an application in Play Framework (2.4.0) / scala and trying to add `play.api.libs.streams` so I can use the object `Streams` in my application.

so here is my *working* `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  specs2 % Test,
  cache,
  ws,
  "com.softwaremill.macwire" %% "macros" % "2.2.2",
  "com.softwaremill.macwire" %% "runtime" % "1.0.7",
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.10",
  "com.eclipsesource" %% "play-json-schema-validator" % "0.6.5",

  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.5" % Test,
  "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.12.2" % Test,
  "org.scalatestplus" %% "play" % "1.4.0-M4" % Test,

  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.4.4"
)
```

Now when I try to add the following line :

```
streams,
```

or when I just add

```
libraryDependencies += streams
```

I get the error :

```
error: No implicit for Append.Value[Seq[sbt.ModuleID], sbt.TaskKey[sbt.Keys.TaskStreams]] found,
  so sbt.TaskKey[sbt.Keys.TaskStreams] cannot be appended to Seq[sbt.ModuleID]
libraryDependencies += streams
```

And I am unable to launch my project.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29311341/4884034), but tweaking by adding '%' or '%%' did not solve the issue, and I was not sure how to use the solutions as I am just trying to add a `play.api.libs` dependency and not an external one.

I am kind of stuck here, I don't understand why **streams** is a `sbt.TaskKey[sbt.Keys.TaskStreams]` but **ws** *or any other key added in the Sequence* is a `sbt.ModuleID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This this case the `cache`, `ws`, etc lines refer not to *packages* in `play.api.libs`, but to build artefacts that the Play sbt-plugin pre-defines as components in the `play.sbt.PlayImport` object, for example [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlayImport.scala#L46).

In this context, `ws` is exactly equivalent to:

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.5.4"
```

The reason you see an error for `streams` is because there is no such component defined by Play, and therefore SBT assumes you are making reference to a TaskKey.

The `play.api.libs.streams.Streams` object should be available without anything extra added to your build if you have a PlayScala project on Play 2.5.x and above.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, it makes sense ! However I am using ReactiveMongo that is not currently supporting Play above 2.4.x so I cannot upgrade *sad face*

Comment: @Daniel In case you didn't figure it out. If you're using play 2.4 you can add this dependency: "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-streams-experimental" % "2.4.11"